# month wise dataset dynamically

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am trying to create month wise data array for my chart. Combining all the sales and purchase value of each month

It will be really helpful who can help me in getting my expected output. I have attached the fiddle which I tried with my expected output to create chart

If possible, guide me with some java script functions which can be useful to me

http://jsfiddle.net/qjsgy6a6/2/

```
var mainData = [
  {
    "date": "2017-01-03",
    "month": "JAN",
    "sales": "200",
    "purchase": "1000"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-18",
    "month": "JAN",
    "sales": "800",
    "purchase": "2500"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-22",
    "month": "JAN",
    "sales": "400",
    "purchase": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-20",
    "month": "FEB",
    "sales": "40",
    "purchase": "90"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-28",
    "month": "FEB",
    "sales": "970",
    "purchase": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-29",
    "month": "FEB",
    "sales": "3300",
    "purchase": "2900"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-03-20",
    "month": "MAR",
    "sales": "600",
    "purchase": "900"
  }
]


// Expected Output - how can I achieve this

{
  "data": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "event": "sales",
          "inventory": [
            {
              "value": "200"   //Jan
            },
            {
              "value": "40"   //Feb
            },
            {
              "value": "600"  //Mar
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "event": "purchase",
          "inventory": [
            {
              "value": "1000"
            },
            {
              "value": "90"
            },
            {
              "value": "900"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "event": "sales",
          "inventory": [
            {
              "value": "800"
            },
            {
              "value": "970"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "event": "purchase",
          "inventory": [
            {
              "value": "2500"
            },
            {
              "value": "2100"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "event": "sales",
          "inventory": [
            {
              "value": "400"
            },
            {
              "value": "3300"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "event": "purchase",
          "inventory": [
            {
              "value": "2100"
            },
            {
              "value": "2900"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's confusing: your data is spread over JAN, FEB and MAR, but your graph in the fiddle is spread over Q1, Q2, and Q3. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @trincot Sorry my mistake, I just posted a part of my chart data.. Updated my fiddle. Any way to get the expected output from mainData object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```js
function transformData(data) {
    return {
        data: data.reduce ( (acc, item) => {
            let i = acc.months.get(item.month) || 0;
            acc.data[i] = acc.data[i] || {
                data: [{
                    event: "sales",
                    inventory: []
                }, {
                    event: "purchase",
                    inventory: []
                }]
            };
            acc.data[i].data[0].inventory.push({ value: item.sales });
            acc.data[i].data[1].inventory.push({ value: item.purchase });
            acc.months.set(item.month, i+1);
            return acc;
        }, { months: new Map, data: [] } ).data
    };
}

// Input
var data = [
  {
    "date": "2017-01-03",
    "month": "JAN",
    "sales": "200",
    "purchase": "1000"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-18",
    "month": "JAN",
    "sales": "800",
    "purchase": "2500"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-22",
    "month": "JAN",
    "sales": "400",
    "purchase": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-20",
    "month": "FEB",
    "sales": "40",
    "purchase": "90"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-28",
    "month": "FEB",
    "sales": "970",
    "purchase": "2100"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-29",
    "month": "FEB",
    "sales": "3300",
    "purchase": "2900"
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-03-20",
    "month": "MAR",
    "sales": "600",
    "purchase": "900"
  }
];

// Conversion
var result = transformData(data);

// Output
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```